# Selecting a field whose label is repeated in subsections

Tags: react-testing-library

I have a form that has some labels repeated, but in different subsections.  Here's an example of part of my form:

[image]

I want to be able to choose, for example, the Days from Section A and also the Days from Section B independently.  To that end, I've tried using the getByLabelText method:

```
it('should display correct value for days field', async () => {
    const {getByLabelText} = render(<MyForm/>);

    const daysElement = await waitForElement(() => 
        getByLabelText(/Days/i) as HTMLInputElement
    );

    expect(daysElement.value).toEqual('0');
});
```

I'm using htmlFor on the label for Days and a matching Id on the associated input element.  Each section has a context provided to disambiguate the otherwise matching Ids (e.g. for days).  For example:

```
<Field label={i18n.days} htmlFor={`${name}_days`} value = {<NumberControl name='days' id={`${name}_days`} value={this.state.days}}/>
```

In this code, ${name} would resolve to something that is different for section A vs section B.  (Field and NumberControl would ultimately create label and input elements, setting htmlFor and id values appropriately).

When I use getByLabelText as illustrated above, it obtains the value for Section A.  But I also need to obtain the value for Section B.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have different options depending on your DOM structure.

If you have a way to query your section—for example with a `data-testid`—you could use `within`:

```
within(getByTestId('id-for-section-A')).getByLabelText('Days')
within(getByTestId('id-for-section-B')).getByLabelText('Days')
```

`within` gives you all the query helpers that are returned by `render` but they are limited to the children of the node you pass to them.

If you can't add a `data-testid` to your section but you're always sure about the order in which the fields appear on the page you can use `getAllByLabelText`:

```
const [firstInput, secondInput] = getAllByLabelText('Days')
```

Lastly, if none of the above works, you could use the `id` attributes since they are unique. `renderd` returns a `container` element which is just a DOM Node. You can use the regular DOM methods on it:

```
const { container } = render(<YourForm />)
container.getElementById('section_A_days')
container.querySelector('#section_A_days')
```

How you query within your `container` depends on your DOM structure.

---

I personally would go with `within` but it very much depends on your use-case.

Comment: I didn't get the second variation working, but the first one worked great.  Thanks so much!